# How to pass data from partial to main view in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, partial, angularjs-ng-include

I have a main view which includes a partial as follows:

```
 </div>
  <ng-include src="'/public/xyz.html'"></ng-include>
 </div>
 <div> 
   <span>{{abcd.Name}}</span>
 </div>
```

The partial has a variable which gets populated on click of an element and I need to pass that data from partial to parent.
The variable is populated in partial's controller as:

```
$scope.$parent.abcd = {"Name":"xyz"}
```

But when I try to access it on the main view its not present.

How to access it in the parent?

Comment: User pub/sub with $broadcast and $on to pass short messages like that specially when Name:zyx is not a property of parent scope so should be be assigned to it

Comment: those both are in same controller??

Comment: You can use services (created by factory) that created shared object.

Comment: @chandu no both the views have different controller.

Comment: @jcubic the shared object is undefined first in the main view and then populated in the partial.

Comment: @infantDev. both are inherited controllers or different controllers

Comment: To share common objects between controllers you use services, you can try use them.

Comment: @jcubic isn't this a parent-child relationship? Can't it be passed via $parent, is it necessary to use services?

Comment: Don't know, maybe it's $parent.$parent if you have controller inside the partial. Check inside batarang how your model look like.

Comment: If it's different controllers you'll have to use `services` or `$rootScope`

Comment: @jcubic $parent.$parent worked, because ng-include created a child scope of its own. You can right it as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution to the problem is ,We can emit the values from the child to the parent using the $emit service in AngularJs as stated below.

In Partials:

$scope.abcd = {"Name":"xyz"};//Object which needs to be indicated to the parent scope

$scope.$emit("setabcd", [$scope.abcd,....]);

where "setabcd"=name of the emiter. User-defined name. We can use any unique name.
       ...     =objects or variables to be notified to the parent scope.

In Controller:

$scope.$on("setabcd",function(event,args){$scope.abcd=args[0]});

where   "setabcd"= name of the emitter.The name should be same as mentioned in the partials.
    args=An array of items sent from the partials.